# How can I retrieve the equation of a plane in each image, given a video?

Tags: computer-vision, camera, geometry, linear-algebra

In my image I know all the points that, in the real world, are on the same plane.
How can I find the equation of a plane passing that approximate them, in camera coordinates?

For example, I know the points that compose the front of a building, and I want to approximate that facade with a plane in camera coordinates, how could I do?

If I knew the depth of some points in real world it would be easy, but without them I have no idea on how I could proceed.

I hope this is the right place to ask this question, otherwise point me to the correct forum.

Thank

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective-n-Point if you have a model of points, otherwise you need to work with lines/rays

Comment: Given that I do not have 3d coordinates, but a sequence of images (a video) could I estimate something given two consecutive images?

Comment: What do you mean by camera coordinates? If you have three coordinates in the real world which correspond with three coordinates you've located in an image, you can generate a 3D transform matrix that would allow you to convert points between the two coordinate systems.

Comment: you need to show your data. -- you either need multiple cameras in a fixed arrangement, or you need a reference object of known dimensions in at least one view of the scene. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_from_motion